# Data Export weekly

Tags: data-export

I have scheduled my weekly data export every sunday evening 7.00 pm.

For the last 2 weeks it's been successfully working, I was getting 65 files of 512 MB each.

This sunday I had only one file of 200 MB. What could be the issue, am I missing anything ?

I tried again today same thing happened ...Only One file. can anyone please suggest or experience this ..

Regards, Ata.